# CodeIgniter query group and count values in multiple fields (same type)

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to build a query in model for grouping and counting values in 3 columns (in one MySQL table) with the same type values: INT(11).

Column1 with values: "1" "2" "3".

Column2 with values: "2" "3" "3".

Column3 with values: "1" "1" "1".

Result wanted is an array with 2 parameters: the number and counter for this number.

For example: number "1" and counter "4"

in my CI model:

```
   public function report_1() {
   $sql = 'SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) as counter1, col2, COUNT(col2) as counter2,col2,COUNT(col3)
   as counter3 FROM table_name GROUP BY ....';   
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   return $query->result_array();
   }
```

in my CI View:
HTML table with 2 columns ("Number" and "Counter"): 
 Number    "1" "2" "3"
 Counter   "4" "2" "3"

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: Can you show what you expect the results to look like?

Comment: **What?** (Lorem ipsum - filling text so comment is accepted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the number of time a value exists in different columns, you will need first to join those columns and then count occurrences of each value.

You will be able to do this by using `UNION ALL`

try this:

```
SELECT
    col_value,
    count(*) AS counter
FROM
    (
        SELECT col_1 AS col_value FROM test_a

        UNION ALL

        SELECT col_2 AS col_value FROM test_a

        UNION ALL

        SELECT col_3 AS col_value FROM test_a
    ) AS temp_tb
GROUP BY
    col_value
ORDER BY
    counter DESC
```

We use the [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to join all columns into one column named col_val and then we use the count and grouping to get number of occurrences of each value.